# Select and insert multiple record from selected values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, where-clause

I am having a User table in which some records are available.
[image]

I want to select **Id3** with this condition **id<5** and insert 4 new rows in the User table with Id2=10000 a constant value 
**For example:** consider row 1 which is having id=1,id2=200, and Id3=300, I want to insert a new record where Id2=10000 and Id3=300
Is there any way to avoid writing 4 insert statements manually. Please suggest to me.

Comment: Make it, say 5, instead of 100, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into users (id, id2, id3)
select id, 200, id3
from users
where id <= 100
```

If would probably be safer to not take in account rows that already have `id2` set to `200`:

```
insert into users (id, id2, id3)
select id, 200, id3
from users
where id <= 100 and id2 <> 200
```

Comment: I think the OQ wants to insert many rows in one of his scenarios.